# exam type android app

Tags: android, android-intent

I am developing an android app for students who can take test and exams.Here my question is that I have set of questions say 50 each having 4 answer options in a selectable listview manner.Now,what i want to ask is that i want them to be called in one activity only and not 50 searate activties.
here's the sample code

```
  /***ArrayList goes here*****/
    stuff.add("I'm noting.");
 stuff.add("I always do nthing.");
 stuff.add("All my efforts");

lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        this, 
         android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,stuff );
   lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

   Button sbt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sbt);
     sbt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Screen5cActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
   });
```

So,one method for doing this that comes to my mind is that take a static counter and keep on recreating that same activity by inflating data from same arraylist but that method gets a bit obfuscated as for storing result and other.
Any,other solutions withh efficiency and better explaination are welcome.

Comment: It's like a quiz game. See [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-ui-workshop-build-an-interactive-quiz-app--mobile-14208)

Comment: YOu can store the questions and their choices and the coorect one etc in a sqlite database and just use on activity with listView , and the data of listview will be selected from database

Comment: I will be posting a better way to approach this shortly. You should probably be using a main Activity, which will handle all the different tests, and then have a generic fragment that displays different questions. Then just have you activity keep track of wrong and right answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, well here is how i would do this.

I create a MainActivity as Follows :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements QuestionAnswerInterface{

private static final String FRAGMENT_TAG = "QuestionAnswerFragment";

private String [] questionsArray = {"How old was John Wayne when he died ?","Who was the First U.S. President ?", "How many vertices are on a Octagon ?"};

private String [][] answers = {{"43","56","34","none of these"},
                                {"George Bush","Barrack Obama","George Washington","none of these"},
                                {"6","4","8","none of these"}
                                };

private QuestionAnswerFragment fragment                 = null;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> answersListOfLists = null;
private ArrayList<String> answersList                   = null;
private ArrayList<String> questionsList                 = null;

// Ultimate Holder to Link the ArrayLists
private HashMap<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> questionAnswerList = null;

@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // -------- Setup the Questions -------
    setupQuestions(questionsArray, answers);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    if(fragment == null)
    {
        // Create the Fragment
        fragment = (QuestionAnswerFragment) QuestionAnswerFragment.newInstance(new Bundle(), "Test Example" , questionAnswerList);

        ft.add(R.id.frameLayoutTest, fragment, FRAGMENT_TAG);
        ft.commit();

    }else{

        fragment = (QuestionAnswerFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG);
        ft.show(fragment);

    }


}

private void setupQuestions(String [] questions, String[][] answers) 
{
    // The Ultimate Wrapper
    questionAnswerList = new HashMap<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>();

    // ArrayList to hold the List of lists of answers
    answersListOfLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    // ArrayList to hold the list of Questions
    questionsList = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Loop Through the Questions
    for(int i = 0; i < questionsArray.length ; i++)
    {
        // Add them to the List
        questionsList.add(questions[i]);
    }


    //*** Magic Stuff ***
    for(int l = 0; l < answers.length ; l++)
    {
        // Needs to be created each time we add a new set of answers    
        answersList = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Loop through the inner array values
        for(int m = 0; m < answers[l].length ; m++)
        {
            // Add the Answers for index l using values of index m
            answersList.add(answers[l][m]);

        }

        answersListOfLists.add(answersList);

    }

    questionAnswerList.put(questionsList, answersListOfLists);
}

@Override
public void sendBackAnswer(String answer) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



}
```

And then My Fragment Class :

```
public class QuestionAnswerFragment extends Fragment{

private static HashMap<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> m_questionAnswerList;
private static String m_textName = null;

private static final String TAG = "QuestionAnswerFragment";
private QuestionAnswerInterface m_callBack = null;

private AnswerAdapter m_adapter         = null;
private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> m_answers  = null;
private ArrayList<String> m_questions   = null;

private int m_questionCount             = 0;
private String currentQuestion          = null;

private Entry<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> entry = null;
private Iterator<Entry<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>> iterator = null;

// UI Elements
private ListView m_listViewAnswers      = null;
private Button m_buttonSubmitAnswer     = null;
private TextView m_textViewQuestion     = null;

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Interface

public interface QuestionAnswerInterface
{
    // Returns the Right or wrong Answer to be kept for score calculation
    public abstract void sendBackAnswer(String answer);

}


// Instance Method, so we can share the relevant information with the fragment
public static QuestionAnswerFragment newInstance(Bundle args, String testName, HashMap<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> questionAnswerList)
{
    QuestionAnswerFragment fragment = new QuestionAnswerFragment();

    m_textName = testName;
    m_questionAnswerList = questionAnswerList;

    fragment.setArguments(args);

    return fragment;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Class Overrides

@Override public void onAttach(Activity activity) 
{
    // Default Behavior
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try{

        // Attach the Interface to the Parent Activity
        m_callBack = (QuestionAnswerInterface) activity;

    }catch(ClassCastException ex){

        // Log the Error
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to Implement Interface in the Parent Activity " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    // Inflate the Layout from the XML Resource
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.question_answer_fragment, null);
}

@Override public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // Get a Reference to All the Views
    m_listViewAnswers       = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listViewAnswerOptions);
    m_textViewQuestion      = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textViewQuestion);
    m_buttonSubmitAnswer    = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.buttonDone);

    // Add a Listener to the button & ListView
    m_buttonSubmitAnswer.setOnClickListener(SubmitListener);
    m_listViewAnswers.setOnItemSelectedListener(AnswerListener);

    iterator = m_questionAnswerList.entrySet().iterator();

    // Start the test from the Beginning using the String [0] as the first question
    entry = iterator.next();
    m_questions = entry.getKey();                       
    m_answers = entry.getValue();

    Log.d("ArraySize Questions", "Size of the Questions Array is "+ m_questions.size());
    Log.d("ArraySize Answers", "Size of the Answers Array is "+ m_answers.size());


    // Start the Test
    updateTest();
}

public void updateTest()
{
    m_textViewQuestion.setText(m_questions.get(m_questionCount));


    updateAdapter(m_answers.get(m_questionCount));

    m_questionCount += 1;

}

private void updateAdapter(ArrayList<String> arrayList) 
{
        m_adapter = new AnswerAdapter(getActivity(), arrayList);
        m_listViewAnswers.setAdapter(m_adapter);    
}

private OnItemSelectedListener AnswerListener = new OnItemSelectedListener()
{

    @Override public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id) 
    {
        // Get the Position of the List Item Selected
        // Check if its correct or do what you need to do.
        m_callBack.sendBackAnswer(m_listViewAnswers.getSelectedItem().toString());
    }

    @Override public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) { }

};


// Submits the Answer to the Parent Activity    
private OnClickListener SubmitListener = new OnClickListener()
{

    @Override public void onClick(View view) 
    {
        if(m_questionCount != m_questions.size())
        {
            // Notify the Parent that we want to share the Users choice
            updateTest();
        }else{

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You have reached the End of the Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

};

}
```

And finally the Adapter Class

```
public class AnswerAdapter extends BaseAdapter{


//----------------------------------------------------------
// Member Variables
private Context m_classContext      = null;
private ArrayList<String> m_answers = null;
private LayoutInflater m_inflater   = null;

//----------------------------------------------------------
// Constructor
public AnswerAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> answers)
{
    this.m_classContext = activity;
    this.m_answers = answers;

    this.m_inflater = LayoutInflater.from(m_classContext);

}

// RowContainer
public class Row
{
    TextView m_textAnswer;
    CheckBox m_selectedAnswer;
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------
// Class Overrides

@Override public int getCount() 
{
    int count = 0;

    if(m_answers.size() > 0)
    {
        count = m_answers.size();
    }

    return count;
}

@Override public Object getItem(int position) 
{
    // return the Item at the current position
    return m_answers.get(position);
}

@Override public long getItemId(int position) 
{
    // Return the current items position
    return position;
}

@Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    Row theRow ;

    if(convertView == null){

        theRow = new Row();

        convertView = m_inflater.inflate(R.layout.answer_row_item, null);
        theRow.m_textAnswer = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewAnswer);
        theRow.m_selectedAnswer = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxAnswer);

        convertView.setTag(theRow);

    }else{
        theRow = (Row) convertView.getTag();
    }

    theRow.m_textAnswer.setText(m_answers.get(position).toString());

    return convertView;
}

}
```

So Thats how i would approach this.

Use the Main Activity to Create new Tests, and then use the Interface to Share the results with the parent, so you can calculate totals and scores.

Answer (score 0):

create one Pojo class with variables question.ans1 to ans4

```
i.e
  class Question{
     String question;
     String ansOne;
     String ansTwo;
     String ansThree;
      String ansFour;
     String correctAns;
     String selectedAnswer;

}
```

Now generate an arraylist with 50 questions;

ArrayList list=new ArrayList();

now generate list view with one text view for question and four check boxes for 4 answers.